# How to get data from database in my android table view as columns and Restrict the no. of row as 10 as per page display

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I have done following coding for deriving data's from table and displayed in the android view as a Table columns and rows.

**The Database coding is**

```
public List<Country> getAllCountry()
{
    List<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();

    //select query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM COUNTRY_LIST";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);


    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext())
    {
         Country country = new Country();
            country.setId(cursor.getString(0));
            country.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            country.setNationalty(cursor.getString(2));
            country.setDate(cursor.getString(3));


            // Adding person to list
            countryList.add(country);
    }

    return countryList;

}
```

**The XML is**

```
<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tab">
  <TableRow
      >        
  </TableRow>    
</TableLayout>
```

**The Activity Coding is**

```
List<Country> country = db.getAllCountry();

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Country c: country)
    {               
        builder.append(c.getId()).append(";")
            .append(c.getName()).append(";")
            .append(c.getNationalty()).append(";")
            .append(c.getDate()).append("_");
    }
    //tv.setText(builder.toString());

    builder.toString();

    String st = new String(builder);
    Log.d("Main",st);
    String[] rows  = st.split("_");
    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab);
    tableLayout.removeAllViews();

    for(int i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        Log.d("Rows",rows[i]);
        String row  = rows[i];
        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        final String[] cols = row.split(";");

        Handler handler = null;

        for (int j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {             
            final String col = cols[j];                                 
            TextView columsView = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            columsView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            columsView.setTextColor(color.black);
            columsView.setText(String.format("%7s", col));                                
            Log.d("Cols", String.format("%7s", col));
            tableRow.addView(columsView);                
            }
         tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

    }
```

I have the above programs to display the values form database.

Now I want to restrict the no. of rows to be displayed to be 10 and moving to next ten by clicking next.

Please give advice to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Dinesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, 
                new String[] {NAME_OF_COLUMNS} ,
                null, null, null, null, null ,limit);
```

Pass Integer Number as a value of limit as per your need

Comment: Thanks David, It works. 
**If I want to see the next 10 values what I want to do?**
Please advice to solve this.